# Reading tab delimited file in R missing rows

Tags: r

I'm attempting to read this file into R: https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=hdl:1902.1/21447# (the commoncontent2012.tab file)

When I use `read.delim()` everything at first seems ok.  However, there are only about two-thirds of the observations that there should be.  When using `read.table()` it imports the correct number of rows.  However, there are other problems with the column names.

Comment: Please include a small subset of the data in this post. Avoid linking to off-site resources as they may go offline without notice. Additionally, why don't you download RData version and import it into R with `load`?

Comment: So the problem seems to be related to the quoting.  When it is set to `quote = ''` then it has the correct number of rows.  That is creating some problems for the text strings...

Answer (score 1):

The file (I thought)  you mentioned is not a tab-separated file, despite what the website might lead you to assume. It is a Stata-formatted file with an extension of '.dta' so use `read.dta` from package foreign:

```
 require(foreign)
 inp <- read.dta("~/Downloads/commoncontent2012.dta")
 str(inp)
# a really "wide" file
'data.frame':   54535 obs. of  479 variables:
 $ V101                           : int  162390854 162397903 162377974 164027062 164852532 166088596 162312322 162347328 162138459 162263731 ...
 $ V103                           : num  0.213 0.572 0.371 0.511 0.788 ...
 $ comptype                       : Factor w/ 13 levels "Windows Desktop",..: 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ inputzip                       : int  NA NA 92637 NA NA NA 33914 NA NA NA ...
 $ birthyr                        : int  1928 1947 1923 1967 1944 1956 1937 1931 1956 1954 ...
 $ gender                         : Factor w/ 4 levels "Male","Female",..: 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ educ                           : Factor w/ 8 levels "No HS","High school graduate",..: 6 5 6 3 6 5 3 2 3 6 ...
 $ race                           : Factor w/ 10 levels "White","Black",..: 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ hispanic                       : Factor w/ 4 levels "Yes","No","Skipped",..: 2 2 2 2 NA 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ votereg                        : Factor w/ 5 levels "Yes","No","Don't know",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ regzip                         : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 # snipped the rest of the output
```

But then I also looked at the file named `dataverse.zip` that when expanded included a `commoncontent.tab` file. When read with `read.delim` I get:

```
> inp2 <- read.delim("~/Downloads/dataverse_files/commoncontent2012.tab")
> str(inp2)
'data.frame':   30140 obs. of  479 variables:
 $ V101                           : int  162390854 162397903 162377974 164027062 164852532 166088596 162312322 162347328 162138459 162263731 ...
 $ V103                           : num  0.213 0.572 0.371 0.511 0.788 ...
 $ comptype                       : int  2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ inputzip                       : int  NA NA 92637 NA NA NA 33914 NA NA NA ...
 $ birthyr                        : Factor w/ 78 levels "__NA__","1918",..: 12 31 7 51 28 40 21 15 40 38 ...
 $ gender                         : int  1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ educ                           : int  6 5 6 3 6 5 3 2 3 6 ...
 $ race                           : int  1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# rest of output deleted
```

So how does this compare with what you think should be in these files or what you are seeing, since you didn't say precisely what your problems were.